# Why does my checkout button not work all of a sudden?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app that I have been developing, that used to work up until some recent changes.

I ran a bundle update, and a bunch of gems updated. Since then (or around that time) my checkout process doesn't work and I can't figure out what is causing the issue.

I don't have any errors in my development.log file and no errors in my JS console.

You can check out [the site here](http://uibuytes.herokuapp.com/items/notepad-with-lines).

For login credentials, use: abc@test.com/testing123   (where the email is user, and the latter is pw).

Add that item to your cart, then go through the checkout process.

Enter some fake credentials, and use the credit card number: 4111111111111111 (verification number can be any 3 digit number, expiry any date after today).

Once you click checkout, you will see that the form isn't submitted.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why.

Would love to hear some thoughts on how I may either further troubleshoot this or tell me what is causing this.

Thanks.

P.S. This isn't a Heroku issue - I have this problem locally too. I am using the piggybak shopping cart gem, and the gem maintainers have not been able to replicate this error on their end. So I am further flummoxed :(

Answer (score 1):

I followed your instructions and I got the error on clicking 'Create Order'.

```
sjsonp1369201390573({
        "error": {
        "message": "The 'exp_year' parameter should be an integer (instead, is undefined).",
        "type": "card_error",
        "param": "exp_year",
        "code": "invalid_expiry_year"
    }
}
, 402)
```

This is not coming in JS console. Instead your app is creating additional JS script file like:

```
https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens?card[number]=undefined&card[cvc]=undefined&card[exp_month]=undefined&card[exp_year]=undefined&key=pk_u0E6vMzPGDJlYmyLqr83LCahMTL5e&callback=sjsonp1369201390573&_method=POST
```

Even though the error seems to be straight-forward, since I have not used AJAXQ or any other piggyback JS system, I guess you need to step through your program to catch this exception.

HTH.

Comment: Did it create that exact URL string? If so, that's an issue because I specified the `v2` Stripe URL - versus `v1`. That may actually be the issue....now that I think about it.

Comment: Yes, it is creating that exact URL string. A new one with same string everytime I click on Create Order button.

Comment: Hrmm...ok...lemme try something.

Comment: I thought it may have been because I was using `js.stripe.com/v2` when the gem instructions said I should be using `js.stripe.com/v1`. But I just changed it locally and I am still getting the same error. I am not sure how you got that URL being spit out, but the functionality is the same for me.

Comment: Could you post your HTML for card details and submission code for the same? It seems that you are not getting any card details from the form.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the piggybak_stripe gem is looking for credit card details using class selectors that you don't have:

```
number: $('.card-number').val(),
cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
```

so, after I added appropriate classes to the inputs (adding a `card-number` class to the `piggybak_order[line_items_attributes][0][payment_attributes][number]` input and so on), and using "4242424242424242" as the card number the form submits. Validation still fails on lots of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON answer is:

```
  "error": {
    "message": "The 'exp_year' parameter should be an integer...",
    "type": "card_error",
    "param": "exp_year",
    "code": "invalid_expiry_year"
  }
```

Follow up the error message and add the appropriate class to html elements on page. As an example, in line 427 (html code) you have:

```
<select id="piggybak_order_line_items_attributes_0_payment_attributes_year" name="piggybak_order[line_items_attributes][0][payment_attributes][year]">
```

Add the follow selector **"exp_year"**:

```
<select class="exp_year" id="piggybak_order_line_items_attributes_0_payment_attributes_year" name="piggybak_order[line_items_attributes][0][payment_attributes][year]" >
```

The elements with missing selectors are:

- card[cvc]
- card[exp_month]
- card[exp_year]
- card[number]

Add these 4 classes and be happy